# Remote Access WAMP from phone

Tags: apache, permissions, wamp, local, configure

I've the same problem as describe in this question

[Forbidden error when accessing wamp from local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413967/forbidden-error-when-accessing-wamp-from-local-network?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

I tried all this thing but doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem.

in `httpd.conf`file change the following

```
DocumentRoot "J:/wamp/www/"
#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

and this too,

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Allow,Deny 
    Allow from all 
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 
</Directory>
```

and it works fine for me.

I found the solution from [Github](https://gist.github.com/samvaughton/6790739/revisions)